# which lib belongs to deb

Tags: linux, deb

I can explore a given deb packets with `ar –p` or I can extract the contents of the deb with `ar –x` so that I can see the contents of the deb.

My question is vice-versa. I want to know for a given lib from which deb packets the lib stems.

Of course I could build a dummy deb which contains the lib, the install would fail and the error message would tell me in which deb the lib is. But is there an easier way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only `dpkg -S <filename>` provides always the correct answer. Two examples:

deb which is part of the repository:

`root@ReelBox60:/usr/lib# apt-file search libusbmuxd.so.2
libusbmuxd2: /usr/lib/libusbmuxd.so.2
root@ReelBox60:/usr/lib# dpkg -S libusbmuxd.so.2
libusbmuxd2: /usr/lib/libusbmuxd.so.2`

local deb:

`root@ReelBox60:/usr/lib# apt-file search libreelsearchapi.so
root@ReelBox60:/usr/lib# dpkg -S libreelsearchapi.so
libreelaudiodb: /usr/lib/libreelsearchapi.so`

In this case, the local deb is not shown by `apt-file search`

Comment: By 'local deb' do you mean a package you made yourself, as in not part of the repository?

Comment: exactly and you can see the difference.

Comment: Okay, so that's the thing - dpkg only works for local packages, it will not find anything outside what's on the target machine while apt-file will search the entire repository for your files

Comment: Sorry, it is exactly vice versa. Please have a look to the example above. `apt-file` looks only into the repository only and `dpkg` looks into the repository and includes local packages.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
First, run `apt-file update`
Then use `apt-file search <filename>` to see which package has it

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot to mention two things: 1. apt-file update 2. apt-file search <filename>

Comment: It works only 50% because it looks only for deb packages which can be downloaded with apt-get. It doesn't work for self-installed deb packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! It is `dpkg -S <filename>`. This command searches the repository and looks into local packages.

Comment: This will only work locally, if the package is not installed, it won't find anything

Comment: No, this works 100%. it looks for deb packages which can be downloaded with apt-get and it works for self-installed deb packages.

Comment: Please see answer with a local and with a general deb.